# How to add tap gesture on each segment of a Piechart using UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext arc

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart

I am trying to create a `Piechart` using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` for drawing, I want to add tap gesture on the piechart to recognize if the tap point inside each segment. Please find the code below for drawing Piechart and the ViewController where the clas . is used,

**PiechartView.swift**

```
    import UIKit

    private extension CGFloat {

    /// Formats the CGFloat to a maximum of 1 decimal place.
    var formattedToOneDecimalPlace : String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self.native)) ?? "\(self)"
    }
}

    /// Defines a segment of the pie chart
    struct Segment {

    /// The color of the segment
    var color : UIColor

    /// The name of the segment
    var name : String

    /// The value of the segment
    var value : CGFloat
}

class PieChartView: UIView {

    /// An array of structs representing the segments of the pie chart
    var segments = [Segment]() {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } // re-draw view when the values get set
    }

    /// Defines whether the segment labels should be shown when drawing the pie chart
    var showSegmentLabels = true {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    /// Defines whether the segment labels will show the value of the segment in brackets
    var showSegmentValueInLabel = false {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    /// The font to be used on the segment labels
    var segmentLabelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) {
        didSet {
            textAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = segmentLabelFont
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    private let paragraphStyle : NSParagraphStyle = {
        var p = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        p.alignment = .center
        return p.copy() as! NSParagraphStyle
    }()

    private lazy var textAttributes : [String : Any] = {
        return [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : self.paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName : self.segmentLabelFont]
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isOpaque = false // when overriding drawRect, you must specify this to maintain transparency.
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // get current context
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // radius is the half the frame's width or height (whichever is smallest)
        let radius = min(frame.width, frame.height) * 0.5

        // center of the view
        let viewCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: bounds.size.height * 0.5)

        // enumerate the total value of the segments by using reduce to sum them
        let valueCount = segments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})

        // the starting angle is -90 degrees (top of the circle, as the context is flipped). By default, 0 is the right hand side of the circle, with the positive angle being in an anti-clockwise direction (same as a unit circle in maths).
        var startAngle = -CGFloat.pi * 0.5

        // loop through the values array
        for segment in segments {

            // set fill color to the segment color
            ctx?.setFillColor(segment.color.cgColor)

            // update the end angle of the segment
            let endAngle = startAngle + .pi * 2 * (segment.value / valueCount)

            // move to the center of the pie chart
            ctx?.move(to: viewCenter)

            // add arc from the center for each segment (anticlockwise is specified for the arc, but as the view flips the context, it will produce a clockwise arc)
            ctx?.addArc(center: viewCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)

            // fill segment
            ctx?.fillPath()

            if showSegmentLabels { // do text rendering

                // get the angle midpoint
                let halfAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) * 0.5;

                // the ratio of how far away from the center of the pie chart the text will appear
                let textPositionValue : CGFloat = 0.67

                // get the 'center' of the segment. It's slightly biased to the outer edge, as it's wider.
                let segmentCenter = CGPoint(x: viewCenter.x + radius * textPositionValue * cos(halfAngle), y: viewCenter.y + radius * textPositionValue * sin(halfAngle))

                // text to render – the segment value is formatted to 1dp if needed to be displayed.
                let textToRender = showSegmentValueInLabel ? "\(segment.name) (\(segment.value.formattedToOneDecimalPlace))" : segment.name

                // get the color components of the segement color
                guard let colorComponents = segment.color.cgColor.components else { return }

                // get the average brightness of the color
                let averageRGB = (colorComponents[0] + colorComponents[1] + colorComponents[2]) / 3

                // if too light, use black. If too dark, use white
                textAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = (averageRGB > 0.7) ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white

                // the bounds that the text will occupy
                var renderRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: textToRender.size(attributes: textAttributes))

                // center the origin of the rect
                renderRect.origin = CGPoint(x: segmentCenter.x - renderRect.size.width * 0.5, y: segmentCenter.y - renderRect.size.height * 0.5)

                // draw text in the rect, with the given attributes
                textToRender.draw(in: renderRect, withAttributes: textAttributes)
            }

            // update starting angle of the next segment to the ending angle of this segment
            startAngle = endAngle
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let pieChartView = PieChartView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pieChartView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 400)

    pieChartView.segments = [
        Segment(color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 31.0/255.0, blue: 73.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), name:"Red", value: 57.56),
        Segment(color: UIColor(red:1.0, green: 138.0/255.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), name: "Orange", value: 30),
        Segment(color: UIColor(red: 122.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), name: "Purple", value: 27),
        Segment(color: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 222.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), name: "Light Blue", value: 40),
        Segment(color: UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 241.0/255.0, blue: 183.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), name: "Green", value: 25),
        Segment(color: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), name: "Blue", value: 38)
    ]

    pieChartView.segmentLabelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    pieChartView.showSegmentValueInLabel = true

    view.addSubview(pieChartView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Please let me know how do I add tap gesture on each segment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, good question. I've never used a piechart in iOS, but I use `UIGestureRecognizers` alot. Have you tried using `UIView.layer` and `hitTest()`? From what I see you've defined things well enough - be it views, layer, or just frames within a view. Add (if needed) a `CALayer` for each "segment" and check if `hitTest()` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks...The challenge I am facing is with the arc, do you think `CALayer` will help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at https://github.com/dilipajm/piechart

Though it's in `Objective C` but we can try to do the same with `swift` too.